# Changing Auto-Growth Setting in AOAG for log file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transaction-log, auto-growth

We are on AOAG SQL Server 2014.

I am planning to change Auto-Growth setting from % --> MBs for log file.

Do I need to change the setting in all Replicas or only Primary Replica?

Answer (score 1):

Set it on Primary replica only and it gets applied to all secondaries.

You can test it out on a small db .. add it to availability group and change the autogrowth setting.